# Using a Composite Primary Key across it's full range of values

Tags: mysql

I have a table used to collect timeseries data from thousands of IOT devices every second. This table has a composite primary key to cluster the data for each device to increase the speed of lookups:

```
CREATE TABLE 'device_data' (
  device_id int NOT NULL,
  timestamp datetime NOT NULL,
  temperature float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (device_id,`time)
)
```

I need to delete data older than a year. This can be done efficiently using the primary key on a single device:

```
DELETE FROM device_data
  WHERE device_id = 42
  AND timestamp <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR LIMIT 10000;
```

**How can I do this across the full range of devices using the index?**

I've tried the following query, but it doesn't use the index:

```
DELETE FROM device_data WHERE device_id in
  (SELECT device_id FROM device_data GROUP BY device_id)
  AND timestamp <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR LIMIT 10000;
```

I have a script that selects the device_id's in batches of 100 and then makes a second delete query with these 100 device_id's hard-coded, efficiently using the index.

However, I'd really like to know:

**Why can't MySQL use this index across the full range? The data seems to be efficiently ordered and clustered?**

Comment: How many unique devices do you have in the table? One quick and easy solution would be to get those device IDs, loop it in the script and use query #1 to perform delete operation.

Comment: *How can I do this across the full range of devices using the index?* Add secondary index (not unique) by ```(`timestamp`)```. But remember - if the amount of rows to be deleted is over 5-7% then the index is not effective, and tablescan is the best option.

Comment: One more option is partitioning. If you'll create RANGE partitions by the date (for example, monthly) then you can simply drop those partitions which are too old.

Comment: @Samir thanks very much for the suggestion - there are around 10,000 devices. At the moment, I have a script that loops through in batches of 100, as the devices are not always actively producing measurements.

Comment: Thanks @Akina - an additional index doesn't seem like a good option. The data is already indexed and clustered correctly by the primary key and can be deleted in batches. The table contains 10's of billions of rows, and an additional index will use a lot of extra storage. Partitioning could potentially work, but ideally we'd keep exactly a year of data, rather than the whole extra month.

Comment: *ideally we'd keep exactly a year of data* Create an event which is fired often enough (for example, each hour) and deletes old rows. The amount of rows to be deleted for one firing won't be too large.

Comment: @Akina - Thanks, but this won't work as MySQL will have to do a full table scan to find the rows to delete. I already have a workaround script that works, but I would like to know *why* MySQL can't do this.

Comment: *I would like to know why MySQL can't do this* None DBMS can use index by non-prefixed column. You may, of course, iterate device_id-by-device_id, but I doubt that this will be fast (you may try to use parametrized dynamic SQL - it may be more fast than regular iteration).